# Java drag and drop (Swing) from Chrome on Ubuntu

Tags: java, swing, google-chrome, ubuntu, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement drag and drop to receive URL items from a web browser. Drag and drop works fine for almost everything (files from Dolphin, URLs from LibreWolf, document objects (e.g. images) from LibreWolf), but fails (i.e. does nothing at all) when I try to drop anything (URLs, images) from Chrome (or Brave). Drag and drop from Chrome to Dolphin seems to work just fine.

```
public class Main
{
    private final JFrame frame;

    private Main ()
    {
        frame = new JFrame ();
        frame.setSize (640, 480);
        //
        // window init stuff
        //
        frame.setVisible (true);

        // add handler to exit on window close
        frame.addWindowListener (new WindowAdapter ()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit (0);
            }
        });

        // drop handler to deal with receiving drag
        // and drop events
        frame.setTransferHandler (new TransferHandler () {
            @Override
            public boolean canImport (TransferSupport support)
            {
                System.out.printf ("canImport called...\n");
                return super.canImport (support);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new Main ();
    }
}
```

Using:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Plasmashell 5.18.8
- Chrome 103.0.5060.53
- Java 17

When dropping items from anything but Chrome (and Brave), I get the expected output showing that `canImport` was called, as expected. But with Chrome, nothing. Interestingly, the exact same code works as expected under Windows.

Any suggestions or more information would be very much appreciated!

EDIT: I've tried it on Chromium 107.0.5304.121 (via a snap), with the same result (i.e. it didn't work). I can drag and drop from Chromium to other applications.